# Laravel yield and section not working properly showing blank

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

in my project laravel yield and section not working properly

**master page** (app.blade.php)

```
<body>
        @include('admin.layout.header')

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                @yield('content')
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery  -->
        <script src="{{asset('public/AdminAssets/assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('public/AdminAssets/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

> @extends('admin.layout.app')
> @section('content')
> Page-Title -->
>
> Today
>             Yesterday
>             Last Week
>
> ```
>     <h4 class="page-title">Dashboard</h4>
> </div>
> ```
>
> @endsection

**addrecipe.blade.php**

```
@extends('admin.layout.app')
@section('content')
<!-- BASIC WIZARD -->
        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle card-drop" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
@endsection
```

**Routes**

```
--first one for my homepage
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
 
--second one for my recipe page which one not rendering in app.blade.php file
Route::get('/addrecipe', [App\Http\Controllers\RecipeController::class, 'AddRecipeDb'])->name('AddRecipe');
```

above code I have one main page (parent) app.blade.php page and i have 2 other child page which page info i want to render on master page using @yield and @section method in Laravel and i used it but it still not working.

if someone help to find out or solve out this issue it would be a great helpful for me .

thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need to use @push instead, because you have multiple @section('content'), the latest section will override the previous ones.

Comment: what "is not working properly"? what is actually happening and what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am trying to reflect that page on app.blade.php so for that i need to include that file. and my mistake is i am also extending layout on include file so that's why it's not working.

thx for you support everyone.❤